# MySQL basic query taking exceptionally long - explain plan looks pretty good

Tags: mysql, performance, join, coalesce, explain

I have a query with the explain plan below.  It's pretty basic, every join is using an index (though not unique), and it's taking 5+ hours.  The largest table has about 100k records.  RAM and CPU are not pegged or anything, no other queries running, no table locks.  The most "complicated" part I have is the coalesce in an outer join.  Is that killing me?

For clarification, I'm joining to the same table twice because some of the records have a user ID, some just have a first/last name. I prefer to join by a unique user name obviously, and one of the selected items is coalesce(u1.job_title, u2.job_title)

```
from utilization_incident ui

left join users_utilization_v u1
       on  u1.cc_user_id = ui.assigned_to_user_id
       and u1.source_system = ui.source
       and u1.data_date = ui.data_date
left join users_utilization_v u2
       on  u2.first_name = ui.assigned_to_first_name
       and u2.last_name = ui.assigned_to_last_name
       and u2.source_system = ui.source
       and u2.data_date = ui.data_date

left join lkp_job_title_service_area jtsa
       on  jtsa.job_title = coalesce(u1.job_title, u2.job_title)
```

[image]

Comment: simple: try running the SQL without the `coalesce`, and see if its notably faster

Comment: Without knowing more in depth with how the data relates (and the exact indices available), it is hard to give much advice; but... yeah, that coalesce as a join condition is probably not doing you any favors; it probably is resulting in a full table scan of both tables involved. You're probably better off with two separate joins to that table (one to u1 and the other to u2) and deciding which joined `jtsa`'s values to use in the selection list.

Comment: Also, it's not all that clear you need to be joining to `users_utilization_v` twice when you could just combine the join conditions. `OR`s are seldom optimal in join conditions, but neither are unnecessary joins.

Comment: `LEFT` collects missing rows -- do you really want that?

Answer (score 0):

The CPU may not be pegged, but what about I/O?

How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.
Please provide the entire `SELECT`.
Please provide the text version of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Pending further details, these indexes should help:

```
users_utilization_v: INDEX(cc_user_id, source_system, data_date)
users_utilization_v: INDEX(first_name, last_name, source_system, data_date)
lkp_job_title_service_area: INDEX(job_title)
```

Remove `LEFT` unless you need it.